# Problems passing variables between functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an anagram program that asks the user for a jumbled word as input, searches a text file for the anagram and prints the words that are anagrams of the input that are in the text file.

```
word_in = input('Please enter a jumbled word: ')


def permutations(word):
    if len(word)<=1:
        return [word]
    #get all permutations of length N-1
    perms=permutations(word[1:])
    char=word[0]
    result=[]
    #iterate over all permutations of length N-1
    for perm in perms:
    #insert the character into every possible location
        for i in range(len(perm)+1):
            result.append(perm[:i] + char + perm[i:])
    return result

permutations(word_in)

def clean():
    list = permutations(word_in)
    print(list)


clean()
```

permutation() returns the permutations correctly but I want to manipulate the list to remove duplicates and search for the resulting anagrams in the text file. How to I get that list to another function? I tried changing the parameter to word or word_in and leaving it empty but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Not the solution but a tip: don't name Python variables "list" -- you're overwriting the name of the built-in type `list`. Use something descriptive like `word_list`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is confusing you. Your `clean` function saves the results from `permutations` in a variable named `list`, which seems to be what you're asking for (though as grayshirt comments, that's a bad choice of variable name). Can you clarify what exactly the problem is with the current code?

Comment: It seems pointless to create a function to call one function as you do in the clean.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return the list or keep the variable global for manipulation?

```
data = permutations(word_in) # global scope
```